# pandas: count frequency (histogram) according to value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where rows are time, columns are date and each entry value is the frequency. How could I generate a histogram shows in each 30Mins period per day, how many frequencies are there?

I currently use `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).count()`.
However, `count()` does not take entry values.

For example, the dataframe looks like:

```
         03/12  03/13
1:00:01    2      3
1:00:02    3      4
1:31:03    1      2
```

Current output is:

```
         03/12  03/13
1:00:00    2      2
1:30:00    1      1
```

The desired output should be:

```
         03/12  03/13
1:00:00    5      7
1:30:00    1      2
```

---

As mentioned by @jezrael I benchmarked `resample` on my dataset.
Here are the results:

```
In [270]: %timeit date_df.resample('30Min').count()
7.7 ms ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [271]: %timeit date_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).count()
7.99 ms ± 49.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).sum()
#alternative solution
#df1 = df.resample('30Min').sum()
print (df1)
          03/12  03/13
01:00:01      5      7
01:30:01      1      2
```

Comment: tks for the alternative:D

Comment: @spacegoing - hmmm, still not sure if `grouper` is faster like `resample`, is possible check it with your real data?

Comment: Yep. I have a large dataset for comparing. I'll let u know later:D

Comment: @spacegoing - Thank you ;)

Comment: Hi @jezrael, seems my dataset is not large at all:P Just FYI